# Adding Azuracast JSON file to my AM HTML5 AUDIO PRO PLAYER in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, plugin, joomla-api, json

I need help for a problem that i didn't found solution.
we have a web radio created with joomla and we start to put our programs 24h/24.
I bought an AM HTML5 AUDIO PRO PLAYER and everything work fine but i won't also that in the player to see teh name of the song the foto of the group, for this we create a JSON file with azuracast server but the problem is how to add this json file to my player to start to see teh name and the foto of the group.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the extension?

Comment: Thank you for joining JSE, Ahmed, please take our [tour] and read [ask].  Have you tried anything yet? Without seeing what you've tried and where exactly you got stuck it will be hard for volunteers to blindly help you.  Perhaps you'd like to hire a Joomla developer. Your question is potentially Too Broad and may be closed until your issue has been narrowed down.  Stack Exchange prefers that Too Broad questions are closed because they often invite vague/unhelpful answers.